# JSP Maven project won't include src folder in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jsp, servlets

I have a simple JSP project configured with Maven. I have a standard src/main/java folder with one class called MyTest.java.

I added this src folder to the build path as usual. When I create a war with Maven, the class is there.

I have checked .classpath and the src folder is there as:

```
<classpathentry kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/java">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
        <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
```

Note it says "optional" for some reason? I don't know why that is.

My Build path is as (the blacked out part is confidental, its just a project dependency, no problem there):

[image]

[image]

My POM file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>[CONFIDENTAL]</groupId>
<artifactId>auth-java-example</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<dependencies>
    //... dependencies here
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

When I go run this on the embedded Eclipse server, this is where all of this gets put:

```
C:/Users/User/eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/auth-java-example/
```

Yet when I check this folder, all the src folder is missing... I cannot figure it out, anything wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your source folder will never be included in a war nor any other deployment, usually.
Instead, the deployment will include compiled classes. These will be found in `WEB-INF/classes` directory and `WEB-INF/lib` for your dependencies, usually.

If you want to include files into your war, just put them into `src/main/webapp`. There is a difference between your class path and what is going to be packaged into your deployment. Also don't confuse maven build path and Eclipse classpath. If your program compiles fine in Eclipse (using a classpath deriver from maven), your maven dependencies are most likely correct.

But there is more to it. E.g., typically, you will need standard libraries in your project which are provided by the servlet container or application server. You will want to mark those as `<scope>provided</scope>` in your maven pom, so it will not be packaged into the war.